# VR on Google Cardboard (android) using Unity ERROR

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, virtual-reality, google-cardboard

I am new to Unity and VR. I am trying to create a very basic VR application using Unity and my Android phone via Google Cardboard.

I followed the steps given here, https://developers.google.com/cardboard/develop/unity/quickstart, https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-sdksetup.html and installed android studio sdk on my laptop.

Here is my scene, hierarchy, and build settings. No error while building. The refrigerator model is my game object, and as you can see the camera points at the refrigerator, at least that's what I inferred.

On my phone, I only see the green background when facing down, as I turn my phone up it changes into white. Nothing else is seen.

Setup images:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOsNl.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTsrf.jpg
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9QSJ.jpg

Output images:
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgWuy.jpg
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDmQX.jpg
[6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lfHU.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the *HelloCardboard* scene is included when building your app, and remove the default empty scene which just contains an extra redundant camera.
You have to do that from the *Build Settings* window with the button *"Add Open Scenes"*.